# error testing perl module sleepycat dbxml

Tags: perl, module, berkeley-db-xml

Has anyone come across and solved this problem with the sleepycat dbxml module.

I built the module successfully but when I run 'make test' I get an error

```
t/XmlManager.t ............. UNIVERSAL->import is deprecated and will be removed 
in a future perl at 
~/Downloads/install/dbxml-.5.16/dbxml/src/perl/DbXml/../blib/lib/Sleepycat/DbXml.pm 
line 461

UNIVERSAL->import is deprecated and will be removed in a future perl at
~/Downloads/install/dbxml-2.5.16/dbxml/src/perl/DbXml/../blib/lib/Sleepycat/DbXml.pm
line 519

t/XmlManager.t ............. 1/92 failed
Error: The flags DB_READ_UNCOMMITTED and DB_TXN_NOT_DURABLE cannot be
used directly, you must set these flags using 
XmlContainerConfig.setReadUncommitted and 
XmlContainerConfig.setTransactionNotDurable. in t/XmlManager.t, 
line 367

# Looks like you planned 92 tests but ran 53.
# Looks like your test exited with -1 just after 53.

t/XmlManager.t ............. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 39/92 subtests
```

Does anyone have an idea what this is about?